# Authorization in Sonar REST/Web API

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube6.3

I have **migrated** my Sonar version from **5.4** to **6.3.1**.
In 5.4 version, there was no login API provided by Sonar.
Hence we were adding an Authorization header in every call with value as Base64 encoded "username":"password".

**But post migration to 6.3.1, the authorization fails with current implementation.**

We tried passing token (generated from UI) as value of Authorization header but in vain.

We also tried calling Sonar login API (api/authentication/login) but it is not giving back any response.

Kindly help us resolve this issue.

Thanks.

**Edit**

Following is the code for calling REST Webservice:

```
byte[] encodedUsernamePassword = Base64.getEncoder().encode("adminUserName:adminPassword".getBytes());

ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
    String target = "http://IP:Port/api/issues/search/?statuses=" + "CLOSED" + "&assignees=" + username + "&resolutions=" + "FIXED" + "&createdBefore=" + end_date + "&createdAfter=" + start_date + "&facetMode=debt";

javax.ws.rs.core.Response response = client.target(target).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header("Authorization", new String(encodedUsernamePassword)).get();

String strResponse = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

Comment: You should give examples of what you've tried. Suggest to use simple tools like _curl_ first. Make sure to [pass the token as username with empty password](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Web+API#WebAPI-UserToken).

Comment: Hello, I tried following login API and I am getting HTTP 200 as a response that shows that login is successful.

Comment: But after calling login API, if I call any other API without passing any Authorization header then it is not giving me any response. If I copy that same URI and call it from browser (post login) then it gives me proper response data.

Answer (score 2):

First thing: *api/authentication/login* is of no help here. Per [Web API documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Web+API#WebAPI-UserToken) , Web API authentication is made through HTTP basic authentication.

So just pass the username/password in the header of each Web API request. And if you use *User Tokens*, as per [same documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Web+API#WebAPI-UserToken):

> This is the recommended way. Benefits are described in the page [User Token](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Token). **Token is sent via the login field of HTTP basic authentication, without any password**.

Comment: Hello, I have edited my question to include the code which I am using to call Sonar webservice. This code was working for calling Sonar v5.3 REST API but it is not working currently.

Comment: If I follow your suggestion using any other tool like Postman then the API is working fine but it is not working if i use a JAVA REST Client. Kindly help troubleshooting this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two changes were made in above code:

1. Added 'Basic' prefix to the value of Authorization header as follows:

   header("Authorization", new String("Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4zMjW="))
2. Removed extra '/' before '?'from below URL as shown below:

   http://IP:Port/api/issues/search/?statuses